# Cannot render SwiftUI preview from a custom framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to code a SwiftUI view in a custom framework.

The reason to do this is that I want to hide sub-views' implementation, since Swift does not provide a namespace. So, I made a sub-framework and Implemented a test view inside of that.

So I want to do:

1. Make an app (name: singleview)
2. Make a sub-module (name: Framework, named `Calendar`)
3. Export a View (name: Cell)
4. Preview in both of them (*)

And I got:

1. Build & run successfully
2. I can see the preview of the `ContentView` of the app

But the problem is:

- I cannot see the preview of the Cell (inside of the framework - `Calendar`) with the error:
  [image: img1]

```
'Cell_Previews' is not a member type of 'Calendar'

----------------------------------------

BuildError: Failed to build Cell.swift

Compiling failed: 'Cell_Previews' is not a member type of 'Calendar'

failedToBuildDylib: /Users/q/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/singleview-cmqdlfabgiintkgnvdpzzagojvzf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/singleview/Intermediates.noindex/Calendar.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Calendar.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Cell.2.preview-thunk.swift:22:36: error: 'Cell_Previews' is not a member type of 'Calendar'
typealias Cell_Previews = Calendar.Cell_Previews
                          ~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/q/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/singleview-cmqdlfabgiintkgnvdpzzagojvzf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/singleview/Intermediates.noindex/Calendar.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Calendar.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Cell.2.preview-thunk.swift:6:6: error: replaced accessor for 'previews' could not be found
    @_dynamicReplacement(for: previews) private static var __preview__previews: some View {
     ^
/Users/q/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/singleview-cmqdlfabgiintkgnvdpzzagojvzf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/singleview/Intermediates.noindex/Calendar.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Calendar.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Cell.2.preview-thunk.swift:21:27: error: 'Cell' is not a member type of 'Calendar'
typealias Cell = Calendar.Cell
                 ~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/q/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/singleview-cmqdlfabgiintkgnvdpzzagojvzf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/singleview/Intermediates.noindex/Calendar.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Calendar.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Cell.2.preview-thunk.swift:14:6: error: replaced accessor for 'body' could not be found
    @_dynamicReplacement(for: body) private var __preview__body: some View {
     ^
```

So, If I want to see the preview, what should I do?

[image: img2]
This is the screenshot of the project

[image: img3]
And this is the screenshot of the failure

I am using Xcode 11.2.1 (11B500).

Thank you!

---

Edit: Thank you Chris! The code for the Cell.swift (inside of the framework) is:

```
import SwiftUI

public struct Cell: View {
    public init() {}

    public var body: some View {
        Text("INTERNAL")
    }
}

public struct Cell_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    public init() {}

    public static var previews: some View {
        Cell()
    }
}
```

And the ContentView.swift (the user of the framework) is:

```
import SwiftUI
import Calendar

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Cell()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: please show us your code, not just the error. This would help a lot.

Comment: did you declare the cell struct as public?

Comment: @Chris like the Cell.swift above?

Comment: did it work now?

Comment: i tried and it worked. And if i do not have the "public" before the class i get the same error as you got.

Comment: Weird.. I am using `public` for both of Cell and Cell_Previews. But it does not work until now.

Comment: ok, then put the project to github and send me the link...than i will/can help you.But i am pretty sure this is the reason,....

Comment: -> checkout my repo: https://github.com/luckychris/publicstructProblem .  -> it works

Comment: Thank you very much! here it is! https://github.com/inq/singleview

Comment: i just tested your repo....works....see the picture i just shot in the answer - preview can be seen without errors

Comment: Omg... so is this a problem for my machine?! It's because I cannot preview on your SwiftUIView.swift also lol...

Comment: But I can preview on ContentView.swift, as like my result

Comment: no, my mistake - you mean the preview in the framework...i meant the preview in the main program ...sorry

Comment: ..and i have no idea why it isn't working in the frameword and how to solve this... :(

Comment: Thank you Chris. I found a weird thing that if I wrap both of structs with `#if DEBUG`, the preview worked well. I think it should be a compiler bug, but let me examine further.

Comment: wow, you are right. But whyyyyyy !? And how did you get to that solution!? i would never have such an idea....:D